# How do I manage my users post before publish?

Tags: posts, users, publish

In my website , I allow to the new user to write posts.

but the problem is when the user write post. the state of post is publish. it is appear in front page.

I want to read it before the publish , I mean I want to approve it if it is useful or refuse it if it unuseful.

I wish you understand me.

Thank you very much ,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What role are you assigning to those users? According to [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) documentation in Codex it should be `Contributor` for users that are allowed to write posts, but not publish them.